# zero knowledge proof of encryption

Tags: public-key, zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there a way to prove that a ciphertext $c$ was encrypted under a given public key, $Pk$, without revealing the plain text message $m$?

Comment: Note that the statement is in NP (the witness being the message and the encryption random coins).

Comment: Do you want a *proof of knowledge*, or a *proof of membership*? Essentially, if you define $M_{c,Pk} = \{m\in \{0,1\}^*\mid \mathsf{Enc}_{Pk}(m) = c\}$, you could either prove that $M_{c,Pk}$ is non-empty (so there is *some* message $m$ that encrypts to $c$ under $Pk$), or you could prove that some specific message $m$ is in it (so there's some *explicitly known* message that encrypts to $c$ under $Pk$, for some choice of random coins).

These are distinct as the randomness used isn't fixed (which Geoffroy's answer discusses).

Answer (score 1):

For most classical encryption schemes from the literature, what you want will in fact be trivial, as it is common that *every* possible ciphertext is a valid encryption of at least *some* message $m$ with respect to the public key. This is not implied by the standard security properties (and does not hold, for example, with respect to IND-CCA secure encryption schemes), but it holds for many IND-CPA secure encryption schemes.

Take for example ElGamal over a group $\mathbb{G}$, with public key $(g,h)$ ans secret key $s$ such that $h = g^s$. Then *any* pair $(c_1,c_2)$ correspond to a valid encryption of some message $m$: set $r$ to be the value such that $c_1 = g^r$ (it exists since $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{G}$), and set $m$ to be $c_2/h^r$. Then, you obviously have $(c_1,c_2) = (g^r, h^rm)$.

The bottom-line is: if you want such a zero-knowledge proof, you should specify *which* encryption scheme you want it for - for some classical schemes, no proof is needed.

Answer (score 0):

For ElGamal, you can use the proof system proposed by Chaum & Pedersen (CRYPTO'92) "*Wallet Databases with Observers*."

Comment: How? this proof show the equality of two discrete logarithms. If your idea is to prove the correctess of the part ${\sf pk}^r \cdot m$ of the ciphertext using this proof, you need to reveal the message $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Given that an ElGamal ciphertext is $(c_1,c_2) = (g^r, h^r \cdot m)$ would proving knowledge of $r$ such that $c_1= g^r $ using a Schnorr proof of knowledge suffice? An extractor that knows $r$ can recover $m$ as $c_2/h^r$.

This is the basic idea for Signed ElGamal, see [https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/~dmst/research/papers/schnorr.signed_elgamal.2000.pdf](https://www.math.uni-frankfurt.de/%7Edmst/research/papers/schnorr.signed_elgamal.2000.pdf)

Note also that for chosen ciphertext security, $c_2$ needs to be tied to the proof of knowledge of $r$ to make the ciphertext non-malleable.

Note that the model in which this proof can be proven is not especially easy. It uses both random oracle and generic group assumptions/heuristics. Here is a more modern proof in the algebraid group model: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/877.pdf

How such a proof can be made compositional to achieve, e.g. universal composeable security is also debateable. Nonetheless, this is the most efficient and practical scheme that I am aware of. Would love to learn about other suggestions and applied cryptography solutions.